# C# Html Razor page Print pdf from html with Colors

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to print a pdf with colors included. I have had some issues with a couple things with that. For some reason the print screen ignores some styling. I am not sure if that is by default or not.

I included this in the css file that is attached to the page:

```
@media print {
#printdiv {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

It does not seem to do anything..

I cannot put @media on the page itself due to the @ symbol in razor pages..

I added this to the javascript and it shows up in the style for the page but it does not do anything either.

Here is my full Javascript on the page.

```
    function printContent() {
    var printContents = document.getElementById('printdiv').innerHTML;
    var colors = document.getElementById('printdiv').style = '{ -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }';
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print with css in razor page you can use @@media print,here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<div id="printdiv">
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
</div>    

<style>
   
    @@media print {
        #printdiv {
            background-color: #1a4567;
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
    }
</style>
```

result:
[image]